# Bind DataTemplate after Task is finished

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a way to bind a datatemplate which is in a resource file that my MainWindow accesses, but only after a Task that is running in the viewmodel has completed.

The idea was to load a lot of data while the view displays with a little progress area... when the progress is done... then the data should be binded... is the dependency property that allows for this?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControls:TabButton Command="{Binding Path=Tab}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Template="{Utilities:BindableResource {Binding Path=TemplateResource}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

Tabs.GetBindingExpression(ContentControl.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();

Works perfect after the progress is completed.